# Eclipse "Correct Indentation" ignoring spaces vs. tabs setting

Tags: eclipse, tabs, indentation, spaces, auto-indent

I'm running Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 (20130225-0426) in Windows and I'm finding that auto-indent (Ctrl-I) ignores both the General/Editors/Text Editors/Insert spaces for tabs and Java/Code Style/Formatter/Indentation/Tab policy="Spaces only" settings. With both of those set, Ctrl-I indents the code with a combination of tabs and spaces, even though Ctrl-Shift-F uses spaces only. The problem is I don't want Eclipse to reformat my code -- just correct the indentation with spaces.

Is this a known bug or am I missing a setting somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Checked on my Juno SR2 (Windows), no problems with that. Keep in mind that Correct Indentation (Ctrl + I) gets applied to current line or selection (unless "Correct indentation" added to "Save Actions" -- in this case the whole file will be corrected). If you are sure you've set up everything correctly (e.g., have your own Code Style Formatter since built-ins' are not editable), then you should report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the "Correct Indentation" (Ctrl+I) will attempt to copy whatever indentation was used on the line of code immediately preceding your selected block. (Even if that line is using a *combination* of tabs and spaces!) If I select the whole file then it actually uses my preferences.

Seems pretty deliberate to be a bug though in my opinion there should at least be an option for it. I looked through the Eclipse bug tracker for a while and didn't see anything.