# Difference in github branch from what I pushed

Tags: git, github

I've edited a file in my java program and pushed it to a branch called 'develop'.

I added a line changing it from:

```
    else 
        message = guess + " is correct. You win!";
```

To:

```
    else {  
        message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
        newGame();
    }
```

After I push to the `develop` branch this is what I see in github:

```
    else {  
           message = guess + " is correct. Let's play again!";
        newGame();
    }
```

Not that it matters for Java. But the indentation is off. Why would there be a difference in what I see in github from what I pushed and what I see in my eclipse IDE? Exclipse is set to the correct branch I pushed to.

Comment: Looks like you are using mixed tabs and spaces for indentation. Tabs can be displayed with different amounts of spaces.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17527819/1256452); see also [Tabs vs Space indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11492179/1256452)

Answer (score 2):

I think this similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726358/eclipse-github-text-format-tab-indent-problem).  Basically, you should probably switch Eclipse to use spaces instead of tabs since, as @mkrieger1 said, tabs can be rendered differently.  Spaces will be more consistent between systems.

You may also have to update the formatter settings:
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter

Create new profile and then click "Edit":
Indentation -> Tab policy